# Mac Alternative to Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection That Supports Aero?

Tags: windows, macos, remote-desktop, aero

I am experimenting with an Amazon EC2 server running Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter. I would like to have the machine run a theme (preferably Aero) other than Classic. Is there an alternative app to mRDC that would let me show a theme over RDC?

Comment: I'll replicate my other comment, in case it helps others: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2009/06/23/aero-glass-remoting-in-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx tells how to enable Aero in 2008R2 ("Desktop composition" in the Server Manager), which is important if this is gonna work.

Comment: I'm not sure it supports desktop composition, but http://www.freerdp.com/ looks promising. Although I tried to compile it once, and failed. I think it needs the sacrifice of newborns or something to compile on OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know only of one alternative to mRDC which is [Cord](http://cord.sourceforge.net). But I'm not sure whether Cord supports themes.

Answer (score 0):

I use [iTap mobile RDP](http://itap-mobile.com/itap-rdp) which supports composition (you may have to enable it in the connection's settings).

It's not free, but does come with a trial.

As far as Mac RDP clients go, this one's the best I used. It's been stable for me, but since I bought it from the Mac App Store one update has gone out to fix bugs that some users were experiencing.

I would recommend it after using the trial, to make sure it works well for you.